# Why does sourcetree want my email?

Tags: git

I'm new to version control systems.

I've installed the sourcetree system for windows 7 and skipped the registration in bitbucket and other online repositories.

When I try to do the first commit, it tells:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

I want all the data to be stored locally on my PC. So, I see no point in authentication. Am I using the right software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is actually from git itself rather than sourcetree. Git is a distributed version control system which is typically used for collaboratory projects with several users. It therefore requires a username and email to help others identify changes made by a particular user.

It is up to you to give your email and real name. You can use aliases or downright gibberish for the fields and git will not prompt you anymore. You can even set these parameters per repository as well. 
For example running the following in command prompt within your git repo should suppress the messages and allow you to commit.

```
git config user.name "alias"
git config user.email "email-blocked"
```

Your git log will show that commit originated from `"alias <email-blocked>"`

I will add that git might be overkill (though perfectly usable) if you are working on a local only personal project. SVN might be simpler for your needs.